# Preventing Trigger Recursion codeLive Questions

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, recursion

A minor questions from the Preventing Trigger Recursion [CodeLive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiWCFXyNk_U).

One main purpose of this video is to create a trigger that will work on bulk DML. The static boolean doesn't work because only the first 200 records will be inserted, and the static list of recordIds fails when partial retry is needed, because the id's that need to be retried will already have been entered into the static list. But if we bulk DML 5000 records, won't it fail at 3,200 records because no matter what method we use (even the best rising edge/filter and increment/decrement methods), Salesforce will cap the maximum trigger depth at 16?

Comment: what do you mean by bulk DML? From the API (like data loader)? or a single Apex insert statement (or Flow Create Record element) with a list of 3200 records?

Comment: From a single apex update statement. What I need to do is when my app is first installed into an organization, I need to add a custom field and fill it. So I have a method that runs a SOQL query to select all account records, and then it just updates all of them to cause the "after update" trigger to fire.

Account[] queriedAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
update queriedAccounts;

Comment: so the Txn will be all 3200 records with each trigger invocation processing 200 - there's no coordination between these contexts except through static variables or database records; there's no max trigger depth issue unless your trigger is explicitly inserting the same sobjecttype (i.e. trigger processes 200 Account records and inserts another 200 - this will be a trigger depth issue).

Comment: Ah, got it, thank you for the reply. I was misunderstanding Salesforce's cutoff of 16 to mean if a trigger is called 16 times regardless, not if the trigger itself needs to recursively invoke more triggers 16 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are updating 3200 records in a single APEX DML `Update` line, then

- The transaction will be all 3200 records with each trigger invocation processing 200
- there's no coordination between these contexts except through static variables or database records;
- Don't forget there's a mx of 10000 DML rows per transaction (assuming you don't blow up heap or CPU before then). You might want to rethink your design to pass the list of sObjects off to a queueable that processes them in chunks

You would only run into trigger depth issues if your trigger is explicitly DML'ing the same SObjectType

**Example**: the trigger context processes 200 Account records and DMLs another 200 . And when those new 200 are processed, they in turn DML another 200 and so on ...

Comment: Thank you cropredy. In response to the bullet 3, that makes sense. I am going to experiment with either future apex or batch apex, because editing fields for every single record with a trigger seems to hit governor limits quickly.

Also, to bullet two, I also misunderstood the role of static variables and thought they spanned all transactions... this quote cleared that up... "Static in Salesforce are per transaction, so the value will be true only for the current transaction. Don't think of static in Java term where static values persist till the class is loaded into memory." Thank you!

Comment: In a synchronous transaction (e.g. trigger) it would be unusual to get 3200 records to save without blowing up CPU unless one is doing the simplest of work and have no associated flows/WFRs, process builders. I'd be thinking async

Answer (score 1):

The 16 recursion depth applies to DML operations that call further operations. For example, let's say you have two triggers, one on account, and one on contact, and these two triggers update the other record.

## Bad Examples

```
trigger updateContacts on Account (after update) {
  Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :Trigger.new];
  for(Contact record: contacts) {
    record.Phone = Trigger.newMap.get(record.Id).Phone;
  }
  update contacts;
}
```

```
trigger updateAccounts on Contact (after update) {
  Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
    [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :Trigger.new)]
  );
  for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    accounts.get(record.AccountId).Phone = record.Phone;
  }
  update accounts.values();
}
```

This simple anti-pattern will trigger a recursion depth exception. Conceptually, this can be caused by a poorly designed trigger on one object, but in a typical scenario, the recursion is caused by two or more objects that update each other.

So, assuming you didn't hit other limits before reaching the ultimate 10k DML row limit, the recursion limit wouldn't stop you if you had a list of 10,000 records that you wanted to perform a DML operation on.

Think of the trigger depth limit the complimentary form of the stack limit of 1,000 function calls on the stack. You can call 2,000 methods as long as you don't do so recursively, and you can DML up to 10,000 rows assuming you don't do so recursively.

Comment: Speak of the devil! Thank you for the response.

That makes sense now. In my case I am actually preventing recursion on a single object trigger (Opportunity Trigger that grabs from Opportunity History system fields (so it needs to be an after trigger), then updates the Opportunity based on those fields). I used the increment/decrement trigger you and Kevin talked about, except instead of throwing an error when the LoopCount > 1, it just doesn't run the afterUpdate() method. And then the decrement allows it to work with bulk API 2.0 thousands of inserts. Thanks for sharing this method!